# XCode universal App

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have a universal iOS app for iPad and iPhone. I created a class with a xib and its for the iPad. How do I design it for the iPhone now? Create another xib for iPhone? If so, how and where do I tell the app to load the xib for the iPhone when needed, because right now it loads the iPad xib and everything is too big of course.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , your view controllers have a method called `initWithNibName: bundle:` .
Do this:

```
MyController *controller = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myController_%@",deviceName] bundle:nil];
```

EDIT:You have to make 2 xibs , right? Name them something like Settings_iPhone.xib and Settings_iPad.xib. When you want to show the Settings screen , go ahead and declare

`NSString *deviceName = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? @"iPhone" : @"iPad";`

After that :

```
Settings *controller = [[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Settings_%@",deviceName] bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I don't need the deviceName if I type in the xib file name myself right? It tells me there is no visible @interface for 'Settings' which declares the selector 'initWithNibName'

Comment: Thanks, and how exactly do I link the new nib to the Settings class?

Comment: You should do everything just as you do in your first nib. Only thing different is to select File's Owner , go to the Identity Inspector ans set it's class to be "Settings" (or whatever is the name of the class you want to link it to)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Didn't even know there is something like an Identity Inspector, I'm new to iOS, thanks again, it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need two nib files. you can uses `initWithNibName` and specify the name of the nib by using using the following code to detect the device type.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

This will allow you to distinguish between the different devices

Comment: I'm doing it this way: 
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

but when I do this: 
            Settings *settingsViewController = [[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Settings-iPhone" bundle:nil]];
it tells me No visible @interface for 'Settings' declares the selector 'initWithNibName'

Answer (score 1):

When i need to do such an application, I made 2 xib file, one for iPad, one for iPhone. The first is created with the view Controller. The second is created by just adding an interface file. I try to get meaningfull names (EG : ListNameVC.xib and ListNameVC_iPad.xib

On the second xib, you need to do 2 things

- File's owner class must point to the correct VC class
- You must link the view in object with the view outlet in the File's owner (else you'll crash on execution).

With all that, you may call at the creation of your View Controller the correct xib, based on the device :

```
ListeNameVC* listeNameVC

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    listeNameVC = [[ListeNameVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListeNameVC_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    listeNameVC = [[ListeNameVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListeNameVC" bundle:nil];
}
```

You can use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM in your view controller if you need to do things differently on iPhone or iPad. For instance if you put a UIButton programmatically, or if you set an image with a name for iPhone and another for iPad

Cdt